# FlashCanvas drawImage NotWorking

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, flashcanvas

I'm on Windows7 IE9 running in IE8. This works in IE9 only because I can use canvas however in IE8 it's suppose to fall back to flash canvas. Here is my source http://blog.jackadam.net/2010/alpha-jpegs/ NOW it seems im having a problem in IE with the context.drawImage not drawing the image? I've posted on the flashcanvas google group but they seem to take some time to repsond so was hoping there maybe a flashcanvas guru here.

```
;(function() {

var create_alpha_jpeg = function(img) {

    var alpha_path = img.getAttribute('data-alpha-src')
    if(!alpha_path) return

    // Hide the original un-alpha'd
    img.style.visiblity = 'hidden'

    // Preload the un-alpha'd image
    var image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = img.src + '?' + Math.random()
    console.log(image.src);
    image.onload = function () {
        console.log('image.onload');

        // Then preload alpha mask
        var alpha = document.createElement('img')
        alpha.src = alpha_path + '?' + Math.random()
        alpha.onload = function () {
            console.log('alpha.onload');
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.width = image.width
            canvas.height = image.height
            img.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, img)

            // For IE7/8
            if(typeof FlashCanvas != 'undefined') FlashCanvas.initElement(canvas)

            // Canvas compositing code
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
            context.clearRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height)
            //context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor'
            //context.drawImage(alpha, 0, 0, image.width, image.height)

        }

    }

}

// Apply this technique to every image on the page once DOM is ready
// (I just placed it at the bottom of the page for brevity)
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
create_alpha_jpeg(imgs[i])

})();
```

Comment: Isn't `img.style.visiblity` a typo?

Comment: LOL yes it was... and i didn't have flashcanvas.swf in the directory either which was causing a problem HOWEVER it still wont draw the image out. I've checked to make sure by the time the it gets to context.drawImage that source is correct and it is

Comment: Use the `console.log` function here and there in your code to see what is and what is not working. That's all we do. That way you will exactly know where you need to tweak.

Comment: I just commented out the context.drawImage(image and uncommented context.drawImage(alpha and it draws out the alpha just fine... however the url's are good for both of them

Comment: I'm using console.log and i've narrowed it down to this line -- context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height) -- however i'm not knowledgable in flashcanvas and was hoping that someone on here might be able to help out :)

Comment: Seems like that typical loop issue. Just write `console.log(image)` where you have the `drawImage` method and you will probably see the reason why.

Comment: OK finally figured it out... this code seems to only work with the older version of flashcanvas AND only with flashcanvas pro... also idk if this is standard but the guy's site that i reference his .swf file is flash10canvas.swf

Comment: Hence the 2nd footnote in that website… :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was it only works with the older version of flashcanvas AND it only works with flashcanvas pro... as noted in the second footer of the website

> This technique uses the globalCompositeOperation operation, which
>   requires FlashCanvas Pro. Free for non-profit use or just $31 for a
>   commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with flashcanvaspro. Depending which flash player it targets the max image size varies. 
Flash Player 10 increased the maximum size of a bitmap to a maximum pixel count of 16,777,215.
Flash Player 9 limits (2880 x 2880 pixels).

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/size-limits-swf-bitmap-files.html

Need someone to update flashcanvas to the latest flash player